# mod_rewrite not redirecting from nonexistant files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am running into problems redirecting pages with mod_rewrite. The redirects work only as long as the original page remains on the server. Once I delete the page, attempts to access the URL result in 404 instead of a 301 redirect.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$
RewriteRule ^calendar\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.org\/blog\/calendar\/" [R=301,L]`

Again, as long as calendar.html remains in the root directory, visitors are correctly redirected to blog/calendar but as soon as I delete calendar.html, visitors attempting to access it are shown a 404 page.

Redirects via mod_alias work correctly in either case,
`Redirect 301 /calendar.html http://www.example.org/blog/calendar/`
but I'm going to need to manipulate query strings going forward and so need to be able to use mod_rewrite.

Does anybody know why the mod_rewrite code fails without the original page still being present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^calendar\.html$ /blog/calendar/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still doesn't work without a file on the server named calendar.html. Is there any reason why apache should be looking for the original file before executing the rewrite? Might this be a problem with my host rather than the code?

Comment: No this rules doesn't require `calendar.html` to be a valid file. You seem to have other rules or code that is enforcing it.